# How to use WooCommerce Duplicate Product Class in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product.html#15-235 in functions.php but it does not work.

```
$wcx = new WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product;
$product = $wcx->duplicate_product('14466'));
print_r($product);
```

This gives me a blank page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the method name to "product_duplicate()" and use "wc_get_product()" instead of "get_post()"

```
$wc_adp = new WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product;
$dproduct = $wc_adp->product_duplicate( wc_get_product( '62' ) );
print_r( $dproduct );
```

Comment: The signature of the function says that the parameter should be of type WC_Product even if the accepted answer works, this should be the accepted one

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a wordpress post object as the parameter, not the post ID.
Example:

```
$wc_adp = new WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product;
$product = $wc_adp->product_duplicate( get_post( '14466' ) );
print_r( $product );
```